# Omit duplicates in left join by expanding cell content of right dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to join two data frames in python. The left data frame has several columns, The right one has only three columns. I want to use two of them to perform a left join, but instead of duplicating the rows which cannot be identified uniquely, I would like to add an additional value to the third column of the left data frame.
I think the following example will show what I'm looking for:

The left dataset looks like this:

```
 School  | Class | participation 
   ABC   |  1a   |  1  
   ABC   |  2a   |  0  
   CDE   |  1b   |  1
```

The right dataset looks like this:

```
 School  | Class | responsible 
   ABC   |  1a   |  Max    
   ABC   |  1a   |  James  
   ABC   |  2a   |  Julia  
   CDE   |  1b   |  Max
```

As you can see Max and James are both responsible for the same school and the same class, so the output should look like this:

```
 School  | Class | participation | responsible 
   ABC   |  1a   |      1        |   Max&James    
   ABC   |  2a   |      0        |   Julia     
   CDE   |  1b   |      1        |   Max
```

If you have a solution that will duplicate the *not uniquely identified rows* in the first place and remove the second row/create the last column in the required way, it would be fine, too.

Some help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [235]: d1.merge(
     ...:     d2.groupby(["School", "Class"])
     ...:     ["responsible"]
     ...:     .apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=" & "))
     ...:     .reset_index())
Out[235]:
  School Class  participation  responsible
0    ABC    1a              1  Max & James
1    ABC    2a              0        Julia
2    CDE    1b              1          Max
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, please be careful with the variable names:

```
df1.set_index([' School  ',' Class ']).reset_index().assign(responsible=df2.groupby([' School  ',' Class '])[' responsible '].apply(list).values)
```

## Output:

```
   School     Class          participation               responsible
0     ABC       1a                         1  [  Max    ,   James  ]
1     ABC       2a                         0                 [  Max]
2     CDE       1b                         1             [  Julia  ]
```